# How to run through string and recursively apply template tags?

Tags: django, templates

I have a string `like this and whenever there are {{template_tags}} I would like my script to {{replace}} them in a {{loop}}`.

Since I can't know what tags are in the string, I need to

- Detect the tags, in this case `template_tags`, `replace` and `loop`.
- Apply them automatically in a template context.
- Return the edited string.

I already have a method that takes the tag name and returns the value to replace it with `def raw(key_name)`.

Comment: Do you mean render a template from a string?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.template import Context, Template

params = {.....}
t = Template('template String')
c = Context(params)
t.render(c)
```

Comment: Rather than just pasting a random bunch of code, explain what you did and why. That way, the OP and any future readers with the same problem can actually learn something from your answer, rather than just copy/pasting it and asking the same question again tomorrow.